# How to combat drive-by downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, questions

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828543/how-to-stop-redirection-in-the-theme-my-login-wordpress-plugin-when-the-key-or-l) which was down-voted within 2 seconds of publishing (no exaggeration). To my knowledge, there were no spelling errors and the question is a reasonable question to ask which follows SO guidelines. That aside, and even if the question warranted a down-vote, is 2 seconds enough to read the question properly?

How is Stack Overflow tackling the problem of rogue or drive-by down-voting?

Comment: Harpoons. You can combat drive bys with harpoons.

Comment: @dilbert: I recommend a water canon. Wash em right of the road.

Comment: It happens. You grow a thicker skin and move on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, now all we need is the whale.

Comment: It took me at least 3 min to decipher the title alone. That's worth a downvote.

Comment: @HugoDelsing then the downvote would have arrived after 3 minutes and not 2 seconds. Informed downvoting I welcome, rogue downvoting I don't welcome

Comment: @dilbert FYI, harpoons were outlawed at the most recent SE shadow convention. The new standard practice is sparkle-rainbow unicorns.

Comment: If it wasnt for this question I would have stopped reading after my first attempt. So perhaps 5seconds. PS> It's not my downvote.

Comment: @HugoDelsing hehe no problem. Sometimes questions are difficult to word, hopefully it made sense in the end :)

Comment: In the eventuality the suggestion should come that there be some sort of grace period before a question can be downvoted, let me point out the following. Some posts are pure gibberish and deserve to be nuked from orbit immediately. Even those that are not pure gibberish can sometimes be evaluated without reading the whole post. For instance, a wall of text that ends with "Is there a library that does this?" Note here I'm not saying henrywright's posts is of this sort but adding a grace period would definitely have a negative effect overall.

Comment: @Louis +1 to a grace period. Perhaps it should start from the time the user opens the question for reading, rather than the time the question is published.

Comment: @henrywright Maybe I was being too telegraphic there but I'm **against a grace period**, *because* of the cases I mentioned in my previous comment. The "negative effect overall" is that the grace period would impede actions that should be taken without impediment.

Comment: Here's the thing - quit worrying about votes because that is not why you're posting to SO. It's not like you get free coffee and donuts when you hit 5000 points or anything.

Comment: @Jay, do you mean... *the free donuts are a lie?*

Comment: *As far as you know....* @FrédéricHamidi But the sparkly rainbow unicorns? As real as real can be but you have to have some ridiculous score to even see one, much less use it as a harpoon.

Comment: @JayBlanchard here's my thing - I'm not worried about the point deduction, instead I'm worried about the stigma of a down-voted question. My question to you - Are you more likely to read a -1 question or a +1 queston? If I post on SO, my intention is to find a solution to a problem I have, not to gain brownie points.

Comment: Honestly I don't look at ups or downs to decide whether I'm going to look at a questions. Sometimes I am more curious about downs because the user may just need a little help forming the question more acceptably or some guidance on how to ask questions. That thought process is driven by the posts here on MSO about low quality posts and attempts to improve them. If the question has 4+ DV's and aren't dead I sometimes just go in for the kill. :)

Answer (score 4):

When hovering over the [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag, it says:

> WordPress questions about programming and administration are best
>   asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Since your question appears to be about programming and administration of wordpress, and 2 seconds is enough to notice that, maybe it was downvoted by people who are fed up with seeing so much new questions on SO that could go on the more specialized stack exchange sites.

That's just a guess that doesn't assume drive-by downvoting.

Comment: Quite possibly true!

Comment: If it's the first part, that would be a shame. Programming wordpress is definitely on-topic here, administrating is not. There being a specialized site does not change anything.