# I feel that maybe we are overdoing the downvoting

Tags: discussion

No, really... hear me out.

What bugs me about the now infamous "meta effect" is that sometimes we hammer-downvotes on very innocuous little "query" posts.

I mean... I understand why I should be downvoted to hell if I say "Let us charge $1.00 by paypal for every downvote a user makes"

But if I ask "Why didn't I get my SuperFrazzle badge?" and that is all, just an innocent "point-me-in-the-way" question, ... please don't subject me to this bizarre downvotes.

For example :

[image]

I know it is a little messy, a little bad grammar... but the user just wants information.

Comment: One single sample doesn't make a proof for your guts feeling?

Comment: I dont think the user was downvoted because he/she asked a small query, instead they didnt make an effort to search to find if the question already exists or not.

Comment: See also the meta bullet of [this attempt to explain voting culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture/251488#251488).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So what? It's not a feature request.

Comment: Downvotes on meta don't count for anything. Who cares?

Comment: @meagar  - touche

Comment: This outcome is so very meta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What bugs me about the now infamous "meta effect" is that sometimes we
>   hammer-downvotes on very innocuous little "query" posts.

That is not what the "meta effect" is. The meta effect is when a thread receives a disproportionate amount of attention due to being discussed on meta, often resulting in an exaggerated amount of upvotes or downvotes. Exercising downvotes on meta is a part of how this website works and is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

> But if I ask "Why didn't I get my SuperFrazzle badge?" and that is
>   all, just an innocent "point-me-in-the-way" question, ... please don't
>   subject me to this bizarre downvotes.

Downvotes basically mean the same thing here unless it's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). It even says so in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The question demonstrates lack of prior research and effort, so users downvoted it. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 14):

The user just wants information, true. The user also received information, in the form of a link to the question they had duplicated.

Are our standards so low that "I just want an answer" should be a defense against the complaint that a question A) does not show research effort, B) is unclear or C) simply is not useful?

Clearly not. Downvotes convey some or all of that meaning. They don't mean "I hate you and your face and your little dog."

In the case of your own question—and let's be frank, you've been around the block enough times to expect it wouldn't be received well—I suspect the downvotes are mostly expressing "not useful" with a healthy dose of "so very, very boring" added for good measure.

People get tired of the same topics being raised for discussion repeatedly with no fresh ideas. This is one of those topics:

- [Undeserved down-votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265179/2359271)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288113/2359271
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287990/2359271
- [How to combat drive-by downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255904/2359271)
- [How to remove down votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272676/2359271)
- [Should down votes be peer reviewed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267649/2359271)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274465/2359271
- [About The Vote Down Thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256626/2359271)

In no particular order. The list goes on. Downvotes are a source of great consternation for many users.

To be fair, it looks like you're asking specifically about questions on Meta. Once in a blue moon, this sort of question yields some interesting and even productive discussion; here are two examples:

- [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884/254929)
- [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272607/2359271)

Something makes those questions compelling to read and respond to. Read them; learn from them. Better luck next time.